# DocumentFragment and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a site that uses a combination of the Google Maps utility libraries; markerWithLabel and markerClusterPlus.

markerWithLabel manipulates the DOM to put the labels on the map. The problem that I have is that this is very expensive time wise and CPU wise.

I would like to know if there is a way of caching the writes to the DOM and flushing them all at once so as to reduce the redraws and hopefully boost the performance.

I've added this code below to show how I am working at the moment. The new marker is the part that seems to redraw for each item added to the map. Probably the worst way to do it, one at a  time.

```
$.rMap.ready( function() {
    per.mapRM = JSONH.unpack(per.mapRM);
    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0, mlen = per.mapRM.length; i < mlen; ++i) {
        bubble_color = colorArray[parseInt(per.mapRM[i].b, 10)];
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(per.mapRM[i].lt),parseFloat(per.mapRM[i].ln)),
            map: $.rMap.map,
            draggable: false,
            raiseOnDrag: false,
            icon: {},
            labelContent: '<div id="rental-marker-'+ per.mapRM[i].id+'" class="marker-for-rent">'+
            '<span class="point_border"></span><span class="point point_'+ bubble_color +
            '"></span><span class="bubble bubble_'+ bubble_color +
            '">$'+ per.mapRM[i].r+'</span>'
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer($.rMap.map, markers, {
        averageCenter: true,
        ignoreHidden: true,
        printable: true,
        maxZoom: 14
    });         
 });
```

I was thinking of using documentFragments for example, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably show us how you're generating these markers if we are supposed to help you make it more efficient ?

Comment: First thing that come up in my mind is to draw less labels, using the zoom value to decide whether a label must be wrote or not.

Comment: The purpose of the MarkerClusterer is to represent many labels in one location. Unfortunately, it requires the markers to be added to the map in order to calculate the members of the cluster.

Comment: Oh and using an icon rather than a label is significantly faster too as the labels require more DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing the parameter "map: $.rMap.map" when creating your MarkerWithLabel objects?

I think markerClusterer is supposed to handle that and it looks like you are asking the map to render all of them (before markerClusterer does his job of simplifying things)